# Unable to configure emacs to use python3

Tags: python-3.x, emacs

I am using emacs 25.2.2 on ubuntu 18.04.  I would like to use python3 in emacs; however it comes with python 2.7 and I can't find how to reconfigure. The answer [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23852308/how-to-configure-python-el-for-emacs-to-use-python3-shell) which says to use `M-x customize-variable RET python-shell-interpreter RET doesn't work for me,`python-shell-interpreter isn't found.

Any thoughts?
Thanks - Len

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you check if you've installed and enabled [Elpy](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy)? As suggested on their README, you can achieve this by including the following somewhere in your emacs configuration

```
(use-package elpy
  :ensure t
  :init
  (elpy-enable))
```

This should allow you to set the python-shell-interpreter variable. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to elpy.  Will try it.  Can you explain use-package above?  My emacs doesn't have it.

Comment: Ah I forgot that it was an installed package. [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) is a package available on Melpa that helps organise your .emacs or .emacs.d/init.el configuration. You can follow the install instructions [here](https://jwiegley.github.io/use-package/installation/). You can also install Elpy straight form Melpa, but you would still need to include ```(elpy-enable)``` somewhere in your emacs configuration.